# jqueryUI autocomplete does not function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an array with some data that I want to autocomplete in an input section on the HTML, kinda like predictive text. I'm using jqueryUI and following instructions as per https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ (to do some tests) but the code doesnt work - the data doesnt autocomplete when I fill out the input, even though its set up like the example? Its basically being loaded in order of (I am calling Jquery locally and JqueryUI externally):

```
<script src="jquery.2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

  var locations = [
      "London",
      "Paris",
      "Moscow",
      "Melbourne"
      ];
  $("#start").autocomplete({
   source: locations   
  });

  });
 </script>

 <input type="text" id="start"  placeholder="From" >
```

Comment: it is showing autocomplete in fiddle check dis "http://jsfiddle.net/mmavzmkm/"

Comment: You probably need to wrap your script in a 
$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: the function im using is an IIFE, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
 <script>
$(function() {

var locations = [
  "London",
  "Paris",
  "Moscow",
  "Melbourne"
  ];
 $("#start").autocomplete({
 source: locations   
 });

  });
 </script>

 <input type="text" id="start"  placeholder="From" >
```

Comment: Please use proper cdn links